# Is it possible to control dark energy in some models?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-energy

Dark energy seems like the explanation for the expansion of the universe. Are there any physics models where it is included? Is it possible to control it in those models? I was thinking because the expansion of the universe seems anisotropic it might be possible to control the expansion.

(might need to revisit question in future if the models change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dark energy seems like the explanation for the expansion of the universe.

No. Dark energy is not required to explain the expansion of the universe. There were models for an expanding universe with no dark energy. Dark energy was proposed to explain the *acceleration* of the expansion, once astronomers realized that the expansion was speeding up rather than slowing down.

> Are there any physics models where it is included?

Yes. The current standard model of cosmology, known as [Lambda-CDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model), includes dark energy. That’s what the “Lambda” in the name stands for. In this model, dark energy provides 69% of the universe’s current average energy density.

> Is it possible to control it in those models?

No.

> the expansion of the universe seems anisotropic

In the standard model, the expansion is isotropic. Recent evidence that it may be anisotropic is not widely accepted and is likely [wrong](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2020/04/21/no-the-universe-cannot-be-expanding-differently-in-different-directions/#37c9d9071774).